# Unwinding a Segue effecting the app?

Tags: ios, uistoryboardsegue

I've an app where there are more than 10 `ViewControllers` and there is a `MenuViewController` Which is triggered by all the `ViewControllers`. And `MenuViewController` Triggers all `ViewControllers`. So in app I will not unwind a Segue but keep on triggering the segues.

Scheme:

[image: Please Click the Link]

Does it give any side effect like out of memory or app hanging kind of? 
Will it be fine if I keep on triggering segues without unwinding them?

Question no 2  is

When I trigger

> `VC1` to `MenuVC`
>
> `menuVC` to `VC1`
>
> `VC1` to `MENUVC`
>
> `menuVC` to `VC1`

Now I'll Trigger a segue from vc1 to vc2
and the segue opens two times cause there are two vc1 's which are present in Segue tree
Its the problem

Somebody Please Help ???

My Storyboard pic

Comment: You are not doing unwind segues properly. Please can you post a picture of your storyboard?

Comment: @Fogmeister,, see the link its  a screen shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll eventually run out of memory if you keep pushing new view controllers on the navigation stack without removing the previous ones. If you never want to pop back to a previous view controller, you can remove the complete navigation history after the push transition has finished in each view controllers `viewDidAppear:`:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear {
    [super viewDidAppear];
    self.navigationController.viewControllers = @[self];
}
```

Alternatively, you can put this logic in a central place by setting your navigation controller's `delegate` and implementing `navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:`:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
       didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                    animated:(BOOL)animated {
    navigationController.viewControllers = @[navigationController.viewControllers.lastObject];
}
```

E.g. your app delegate could be the navigation controller's `delegate`.

Comment: Thanks dude its working perfect... I followed the first option self.navigationController.viewControllers = @[self];                                  Is there anything else I need to do

Comment: @Jack nope, this should be enough as long as you never want to go back on the navigation stack.